# Method renderer(_:didAdd node:, for anchor:) not called

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, arscnview

I try to implement plane detection in my AR experience.
I have a subclass of `ARSCNView` with an `ARSCNViewDelegate` extension.

My `cameraDidChangeTrackingState` delegate method is called. However, I've never ONCE see my `renderer(_:didAdd node:, for anchor:)` method being called. Any idea?

```
class ARView: ARSCNView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(frame: frame, options: options)
        let sessionConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sessionConfig.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        self.session.run(sessionConfig)
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ARView: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    //add childNodes to the node here....
    //but, this method doesn't get called
    }
}
```

EDIT: I can find ARPlaneAnchors `session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor])` but I am not sure if I should use this one, because in most (also Apples) examples they add objects to the node of the anchor like shown in my code above. Or do I have to trigger that d`idAdd node:, for anchor` method myself?